# Equivalence of spectral theorems

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I have recently started studying operator theory and am aware that there are different results called the **spectral theorem**. I am interested in the connection (possibly equivalence) between the following spectral theorem and the result which gives conditions under which the *eigenfunctions of a linear hermitian operator can be used as a basis*:

Theorem:

If $a \in \mathcal{A}:= \text{Banach Algebra}$ and $f \in \mathcal{Hol}(a)$. Then $$\sigma(f(a)) = f(\sigma(a)).$$

What is the connection between this theorem and result I gave above? The above result for a finite dimensional case could be stated as the conditions required for a Hermitian matrix to be diagonalizable.

Thanks.

Comment: The theorem you have stated is called Holomorphic functional calculus, which says the spectrum maps nicely if your operator gets map nicely. Spectral theorem is a diagonalizing type theorem about expressing the operator in terms of its spectrum.

Comment: @JackyChong Okay, so are you saying that it doesn't have any obvious direct connection in this case to the usual spectral theorem which involves diagonalizing? This was presented as "Spectral Theorem" in the text I am using.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying there's no direct connection, but they do have slightly different philosophies.

Comment: @JackyChong Okay. Could you please give me an idea of what you mean by 'the spectrum maps nicely if your operator gets mapped nicely'?

Answer (score 1):

Let us restrict ourselves to finite dimensional spaces. Consider the example
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \
B=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
It's clear that $A$ is not diagonaliable (in particular, it's a Jordan block). Let $f(z) = e^z$, then we see that
\begin{align}
f(B)=e^B =
\begin{pmatrix}
e^2&0\\
0 & e^3
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which verifies the claim $\sigma(f(B)) =f(\sigma(B))$. In the other case, observe
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = C+D
\end{align} 
which are commuting matrices. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
e^A = e^Ce^D = \begin{pmatrix}
e^2&0\\
0 & e^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^2&e^2\\
0 & e^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
which again verifies $\sigma(f(A) )=f(\sigma(A))$. I hope this example illustrates that holomorphic functional calculus doesn't really talk about diagonalizability.

Comment: Are you sure that $\sigma(f(B)) = f(\sigma(B))$? I get $\sigma(f(B)) = \{0\}$ and $\sigma(B) = \{ 0 \}$ hence $f(\sigma(B)) = \{1\}$.

Comment: $\sigma(B)=\{2,3\}$

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorry mistake :) Could I ask how you got $e^B =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    e^2 & 0  \\
    0 & e^3 
  \end{bmatrix}
$?  

Did you use the series $e^B = I + B + \frac{B^2}{2!} + \frac{B^3}{3!} + ...?$

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct connection. The spectral mapping mapping is more of an algebraic property in this particular case. To see why, suppose $\lambda\notin\sigma(a)$, and suppose $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\sigma(a)$. Then
$$
               f(\mu)-f(\lambda)=(\mu-\lambda)g(\mu)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\sigma(a)$. This gives
$$
                   f(a)-f(\lambda)e = (a-\lambda e)g(a)
$$
Because $a-\lambda e$ is not invertible, then $f(a)-f(\lambda)e$ cannot be invertible, which forces $f(\lambda)\in\sigma(f(a))$, or
$$
                  f(\sigma(a)) \subseteq \sigma(f(a)).
$$
Conversely, if $\lambda\in\sigma(f(a))$, then there is a homomorphism on the algebra generate by $a,e$ such that $\lambda=\omega(f(a))=f(\omega(a))$. Hence $\sigma(f(a))\subseteq f(\sigma(a))$.